# Redirecting a PHP page that should normally only have a Query String

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I have a page that is the "template" to hold item information, for example:

```
https://example.org/item/
```

Normally though, a user will only ever get to this page with a query string attached

```
https://example.org/item?name=Dishwasher
```

If they remove the query string they will be brought to an empty template page.

I was thinking of re-directing this template page (possibly to homepage) through my **.htaccess** file but I'm wondering if this is bad for SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking of re-directing this template page (possibly to homepage) through my `.htaccess` file but I'm wondering if this is bad for SEO?

It won't do anything for SEO. Google may just treat it as a soft-404 and users may just be left wondering what's going on (although they shouldn't be there anyway). I would perhaps serve an informative 404 with appropriate links to your homepage and other parts of your site. Search engines then get the message to not index the page (without a query string). In `.htaccess` you could do something like the following to serve a 404 to any URL that starts `/item`, but excludes a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^item - [R=404]
```

However, I think it would be preferable to manage this in your server-side code, not `.htaccess`. The `.htaccess` solution wouldn't be able to catch `?name=nonsense` for instance. If your script determines that an "empty template page" would be served (invalid template name, no template name or nothing at all) then serve a meaningful 404 instead.